# Show more and show less button in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have following code:

[my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-voice-dso23)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FetchUsers from "./components/FetchUsers";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <div>
          <FetchUsers />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

What I want to see is when I am fetching data I should see only first two users information, and after  clicking on "show more" it should show all data information from api and button value shoud become "show less" and after clicking "show less" only first two users should stay. I try something as you see from my code but it was working not correct way, please help to correct.

Thank you for helping

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question.

Please, copy/paste your code in code blocks in your question, in case the services you link to are not available anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly this is what you can do:

```
const shownArray = [...apiData].splice(0, 2);
const showMoreArray = [...apiData];
```

As @Mihályi Zoltán said, you don't want to modify the original array.

Then you can change your code to this:

```
{isShown && shownArray.map(data => { return <Users {...data} />;})}
{!isShown && showMoreArray.map(data => { return <Users {...data} />;})}
```

I also think it is easier to user boolean here:

```
const [isShown, setShow] = useState(false);
```

Then you can change text on your button like this:

```
if (isShown === true) {
  setValueButton("Show Less");
} else {
  setValueButton("Show More");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your code to stackoverflow.

The problem is the `splice` method, which modifies the original array.